# SQL GroupBy with MAX and GUID

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, group-by

I've this table:

```
ID                                   Version    IdRoot
887063C3-E1E5-4E76-9EE6-A08300C1DE2E    1       887063C3-E1E5-4E76-9EE6-A08300C1DE2E
ED482E87-D36C-4E50-A6E7-A08300C1DE3C    2       887063C3-E1E5-4E76-9EE6-A08300C1DE2E`
735604E4-25FD-4575-BD88-A08300C1DE41    1       735604E4-25FD-4575-BD88-A08300C1DE41
DA08E433-111D-4C25-9A23-A08300C1DE46    2       735604E4-25FD-4575-BD88-A08300C1DE41
3C0CEED7-0F3A-47C3-90E8-A08300C1DE4A    3       735604E4-25FD-4575-BD88-A08300C1DE41
```

How can I get a SQL that show me only max version?

```
ID                                   Version    IdRoot
ED482E87-D36C-4E50-A6E7-A08300C1DE3C    2       887063C3-E1E5-4E76-9EE6-A08300C1DE2E
3C0CEED7-0F3A-47C3-90E8-A08300C1DE4A    3       735604E4-25FD-4575-BD88-A08300C1DE41
```

I've run this sql: 
SELECT ID, MAX([version]) as maxversione, idroot FROM Table GROUP BY IdRoot

but SQL MANAGEMENT return error: ID must be aggregate or insert into group by.

If I insert ID in Group By, sql not return the correct data.

I've SQL 2008.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [ranking function](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx) [`ROW_NUMBER()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) like this:

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
   SELECT *,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY IdRoot 
                       ORDER BY version DESC) AS RN
   FROM table1
)
SELECT ID, version, IdRoot
FROM  CTE
WHERE RN = 1;
```

- [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/64ef3/4)

This will give you:

```
|                                   ID | VERSION |                               IDROOT |
|--------------------------------------|---------|--------------------------------------|
| 3C0CEED7-0F3A-47C3-90E8-A08300C1DE4A |       3 | 735604E4-25FD-4575-BD88-A08300C1DE41 |
| ED482E87-D36C-4E50-A6E7-A08300C1DE3C |       2 | 887063C3-E1E5-4E76-9EE6-A08300C1DE2E |
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do this with window function like in [Mahmoud Gamal answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18588605/1744834), but there're other solution:

```
select
    t.*
from (select distinct IdRoot from Table1) as r
    outer apply (
        select top 1 t.*
        from Table1 as t
        where t.IdRoot = r.IdRoot
        order by [Version] desc
    ) as t
```

[**=> sql fiddle demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/64ef3/6)

Or something like this:

```
select
    r.*
from Table1 as r
where
    exists (
        select *
        from Table1 as t
        where t.IdRoot = r.IdRoot
        having max([Version]) = r.[Version]
    )
```

[**=> sql fiddle demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/64ef3/11)

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT IDRoot, MAX(version) as maxversione,
 (Select ID From Table Where IdRoot = TB.IdRoot And Version = Max(TB.Version)) as ID
 FROM Table TB GROUP BY IdRoot
```

You can select the ID separately as done in above query.